# Is there an occasional escape to the 9 edits limit?

Tags: support

In far most cases, 9 edits for the poster of an answer should be enough. In some cases however, there can be reasons to do an additional edit.

In [this example](https://askubuntu.com/a/553547/72216) I started with another answer and deleted it. Then I wrote the current answer. Writing an "extra" answer seemed an ugly thing to do, so I replaced the old answer. It turns out however that it will possibly need another edit to make it perfectly working.

Apart from the fact that I think it is a little early to "disconnect" the answer from its poster (me), it is not really the kind of post you'd like to wiki -ize on AU I think.

So my question is: is there an occasional escape to the 9 edits- limit and if so, what should be the way to achieve that.

Comment: There's a limit? I know we get an alarm if it looks like somebody is *needlessly* editing something but I didn't think there was a hard limit in place. I edited an answer on U&L the other day way more than 9 times.

Comment: @Oli Really? That would be good news, I remember in the past one of my answers was wiki -ized after 9 edits by me. It was this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/440247/72216

Comment: I'm actually only up to 10 revisions on that answer (I've just pushed the 9th edit)... So what I say could be wrong... The wiki-conversion certainly was a thing but that has been removed now with the view that we manually convert if many different people edit something.

Comment: @Oli that is great, if it turns out to be necessary, I will edit the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There *used* to be a trigger that if you edited something lots it would automagically turn into a community wiki. This was unfair on people who put lots of effort into improving their own answers so [this was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947/144180):

> We have **disabled all forms of community wiki automatic conversions**, not just for answers but for questions as well. The feature was never really about encouraging substantive edits as much as it was about prevent abuse. And in fact it punished people who made not just substantive edits, but *lots* of substantive edits.
>
> To handle the cases spoken about the abuse cases the system was originally meant to prevent, flags are now raised for moderator attention in the event of several edits.

So we might get a flag come up but I wouldn't worry about it. The only time we really consider something CW-worthy is if many distinct people perform substantial edits on a post. Or somebody abusing the system to bump something up the front page.

More than anything, remember that mods can also remove the CW status from a post so if you feel it's been applied incorrectly, just flag it up for us and explain what needs doing and why.

Comment: FWIW, [here's the meta.SE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits) that lead to the removal of the automated conversion.

Comment: @Glutanimate Thanks, edited in.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.